# How can i apply a sharpness filter?

Tags: angular, canvas

I am developing a tool to apply filters in Angular. I am using Canvas HTML component to apply different filters. I have not got problems with contrast or brightness because the property FILTER has got this kind of filters.

However, I can not use directly a Sharpness filter. I know that I have to use a Convolution with some Kernel but I don´t know how I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers you can use SVG filters on canvas drawings, from which the [feConvolveMatrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feConvolveMatrix) will make it quite straight-forward:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
const matrix = document.getElementById( 'conv-matrix' );
let speed = 0.05;
let pow = 0;
const img = new Image();
img.onload = (e) => {
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  animate();
};
img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg";

function animate() {
  // animate 'pow' back and forth
  pow = pow + speed;
  if( pow >= 5 || pow <= -2 ) { speed *= -1; }
  // we'll use the SVG filter on our context
  ctx.filter = 'url(#sharp)';
  // set the matrix as you wish, here I just gather all closest to the center
  matrix.setAttribute( 'kernelMatrix',
    pow * 1 + ' ' + pow *  1 + ' ' + pow * -1 + ' ' +
    pow * 1 + ' ' + 1 + ' ' + pow * -1 + ' ' +
    pow * 1 + ' ' + pow * -1 + ' ' + pow * -1
  );

  ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
  ctx.filter = 'none';
  
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position:absolute;z-index: -1">
  <filter id="sharp">
    <feConvolveMatrix id="conv-matrix"
      kernelMatrix="
         1  1 -1
         1  1 -1 
         1 -1 -1
     "/>
  </filter>
</svg>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

---